# How to generate a Trailing Average in Python Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, average, mean

I have the following worked out from my last question. I used the formula

```
df['3D Average'] = df.iloc[::-1].groupby('Hour').Value.rolling(window = 
3).mean()\.shift().sort_index(level = 1).values
```

to populate the 3D average column thanks to help from a member. What this formula does is look at the next 3 dates, and average the values that have the same hour as the reference row.

HOWEVER, the problem is that I just realized that my dates are INCREASING here, so what I actually need is for the lag to trail instead of average forward. So, 1/4 should be the first date with any value since anything before that doesn't have enough values, and as the 3DAverage column fills down, it should continually populate the trailing 3Day average of the Value column.

```
Date     Hour    Value   3DAverage
1/1       1       57      53.33
1/1       2       43      42.33
1/1       3       44      45.33
1/2       1       51      ...
1/2       2       40      ...
1/2       3       42      ...
1/3       1       56      ...
1/3       2       42
1/3       3       48
1/4       1       53
1/4       2       45
1/4       3       46
1/5       1       56
1/5       2       46
1/5       3       48
1/5       4       64 *       
1/6       1       50
1/6       2       41
1/6       3       42
1/7       1       57
1/7       2       43
1/7       3       45
1/8       1       58
1/8       2       49
1/8       3       41
1/9       1       53
1/9       2       46
1/9       3       47
1/10      1       58
1/10      2       49
1/10      3       40
```

I hope that makes sense. To be clear, I still need it to ignore the 1/5 Hour 4 extra row, as it should only be using the referenced hour in each row. Thank you for your help !

Comment: Can you simply update your current expression with a `where` clause that checks that you have enough time difference from the first row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the earlier code can be changed this way.

```
df['3D Average'] = df.groupby('Hour').Value.rolling(window = 3).mean().sort_index(level = 1).values
```